# Rubys Yaml problems

Tags: mysql, ruby, yaml

I´m trying to following  abook the explains how to use flex and rails, but i´m facing some problems with the database. I´m also using MySql 5.5

I´m facing the following problem:

```
C:\flexible_rails\current\pomodo>call rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=pomodo_development  --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
pomodo_development database is not configured
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie
.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_
load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb
:2190:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block
in execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execut
e'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block
in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke
_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block
in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke
_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block
in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke
_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke
'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in
`invoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
`standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `
top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `
block in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
`standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `
run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)
>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config`
```

My database yml:

```
# Install the MySQL driver:
# gem install mysql
# On MacOS X:
# sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
# On Windows:
# gem install mysql
# Choose the win32 build.
# Install MySQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: pomodo_development
  username: pomodo
  password: ****
  host: localhost
# Warning: The database defined as 'test' will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run 'rake'.
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: pomodo_test
  username: pomodo
  password: ****
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: pomodo_production
  username: pomodo
  password: ***
  host: localhost`
```

create.sql

```
drop database if exists pomodo_development;
create database pomodo_development;
drop database if exists pomodo_test;
create database pomodo_test;
drop database if exists pomodo_production;
create database pomodo_production;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pomodo_development.* TO 'pomodo'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pomodo_test.* TO 'pomodo'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pomodo_production.* TO 'pomodo'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
```

The bat i use to run the script

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p <db\create.sql
call rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=pomodo_development  --trace`
```

anyone can help???

Comment: Not sure if it'll help. But [mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem is currently recommended MySQL adapter for Rails.

Comment: Make sure that you have mysql gem in your system (see top commented part of your `database.yml` for guidelines) and that lines of your yml file indented correctly.

Comment: And pls remove the password from the code.

Comment: It´s to ident with 2 spaces right?

Comment: I have the mysql2 on my system....

Answer (score 2):

`RAILS_ENV` should be `development`, or nothing at all (`development` is the default).

The environment isn't the name of the database, it's the name of the Rails environment, generally `development`, `stage`, or `production`. The variable should align with one of the configurations in `database.yml`.